# Multiprocessing Module python

Tags: python

I'm programming  a client/server program that allows me to control my clients remotely, my question is:
let's say I have two client connected to my server, so if I'm not wrong, 2 processes have been created, Can I select which client to deal with using multiprocessing module.
here is an example to clarify what I need :

```
  1st client IP: 172.16.122.2
  2nd client IP: 172.16.122.3
```

I want to be able to choose which ip I want to deal with to send data to it.
is it possible to perform such an action ?

Comment: can you also share your server side code ?

Comment: I wonder why you're using multiprocessing for this kind of task